# Google Bigquery Legacy SQL - How to set week number start to Monday?

Tags: google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I've heard the UTC_USEC_TO_WEEK() function in legacy sql allows you to set the start week to monday (and not sunday which is the default). Basically, I want the below date queried to return 1 and not 2.

```
select week('2018-01-07') -- returns 2
```

I've seen how to do this in standard sql but I'm querying a legacy sql view so I can't switch to standard sql.

How do I go about using UTC_USEC_TO_WEEK to get monday as the week start?

Documentation isn't much help and can't find anything online.
Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move one day back with `DATE_ADD()` and then apply `WEEK()`

```
#legacySQL
SELECT WEEK(DATE_ADD('2018-01-07', -1, "DAY"))
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm aggregating and grouping by week as well (however that should ideally be raised as a separate question). All in all, you have answered the question I posted! For that, I thank you @Mikhail Berlyant!

Answer (score 0):

Essentially was looking for this `week(utc_usec_to_week(current_date(),1)) - 1`, so this would return the previous week with Monday as the start of the week.